# Spanish Dead Keys doesn´t work properly on Ubuntu 16.04 when ibus is not selected

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, ibus, dead-keys

I made a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my laptop, an asus UX305FA.
Libreoffice spanish dead keys worked fine.
Then, i installed winehq and playonlinux, and then installed MS Office 2010.
By default, spanish dead keys doesn´t work on MS Office 2010. The way you correct that is opening "Language Support", then in input method, change "Ibus" for "None". You reboot your machine and spanish dead keys works on MS Office. I tried that in 14.04 and works perfectly.

But in 16.04, when Ibus is deselected, spanish dead keys work ONLY in new MS Office or Libreoffice documents. But if i open an existing file, Spanish dead keys doesn´t work. For example, if in an existing document i want to write "cóndor", appears "c´ondor".

This issue only happens in MS Office and Libreoffice, and only in documents already created (not new documents).

How can i solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/774237/dead-keys-accents-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04/774239

Comment: I Will see, Thanks buddy, hope solve the problem

Comment: Thanks, but not worked on my laptop. Finally i downgraded to 14.04.

Comment: I also had a similar problem, and deselecting iBus was not enough, I had to remove it from my system via `sudo apt-get remove ibus-table` for MS Office and Libre Office to behave.

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=235158