# Dead keys (accents) stopped working after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: keyboard, 16.04, keyboard-layout, ibus

Dead keys for accents (like â, è, ç) stopped working in LibreOffice and Pidgin after I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Instead of editing the answer into your text, it would be better to click the check mark on the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 8):

To fix, I used `ibus-setup` in a terminal and followed instructions.  It went back to normal.

Comment: Hi, @dsimard, and thanks for sharing. However, it sounds as a bug to me, and it would be great if you could provide more details, so it possibly can be fixed for everyone. (It should be said that there is normally no need to start `ibus-setup` on Ubuntu nowadays. Whatever you did - not clear to me - sounds like a workaround.)

Comment: I can give more details but I guess that situation is very exceptional.

- I upgraded from 14.10
- I remember having the same problem when I upgraded to 14.10 two years ago. There was an option somewhere about ibus and I clicked it (don't remember if I checked or unchecked the box)
- I recently upgraded to 16.04 with a keyboard setting at `French (Canada)` by default
- The accents with dead keys (example : typing `\`` and then `e` to have `è`)  stopped working in Pidgin and LibreOffice. Everything else I tried was fine.

I'm not sure which details you would need. Let me know if it helps

Comment: I switched to _French (Canada)_ on my 16.04, and the dead keys worked as expected in LibreOffice directly, so I couldn't reproduce the problem. It may be due to some leftover in your $HOME (please note that 14.10 has been unsupported for quite some time, and there is no official upgrade path from 14.10 to 16.04 - might also be related).

Comment: I have the same problem with my spanish keyboards. upgraded from 15.10  to 16.04

Comment: The fix works but... I have to do that everytime I boot. How can I fix it once for good?

Comment: I had the same problem, but i didn't upgrade from any version, it happened on a fresh Ubuntu MATE 16.04  install.

Comment: Many thanks for posting this question/answer !  I figured `ibus` was simply not installed on a fresh Xubuntu 16.04, installing it and running `ibus-setup` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

This issue is better solved by the next input:

---

$ ibus-daemon --xim

---

And, also activating this Keyboard input method system in the *System preferences - Language Support*:

*Keyboard input method system => XIM*

The reason is that, when a language has complex characters like "à", the "Ibus" always generates problems, even to the "very known" non Gnome applications like Skype and Microsoft Office-PlayOnLinux. The typical error is that appears "`a" instead of "à".

My recommendation is that you add the  "ibus-daemon --xim" as *Startup Application* in order to forget this issue forever.

Comment: Thanks. The ibus suggestions hasn't worked for me so tried this now, will see next time I restart X if it helped or not. :)

Answer (score 1):

The fix provided by `ibus-setup` may not work after startup. To start it with the session, add to startup the command `ibus-daemon --xim`, as stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/328073/47206).

---

UPDATE ON A DIFFERENT CAUSE THAN iBUS:

In Kubuntu 18.04 all worked fine. Trying LXQt on top of that and no dead keys in Libreoffice. It seems in this case it was not an ibus problem, but one with the  **libreoffice UI backend** - as suggested [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1772678#p1772678). Solved it as indicated [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1772845#p1772845): edit/create the file `/etc/profile.d/libreoffice-fresh.sh` ( or `/etc/profile.d/libreoffice-still.sh`, as said [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LibreOffice#Theme)) and uncomment/add the line `export SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk3`, then reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem after updating my Debian testing system with XFCE desktop. I solved it this way:

1. Click on XFCE -> Settings -> IBus Preferences
2. Click 'yes' on the dialog whether you want to start the IBus daemon

Answer (score 0):

I recently changed the flavor from Unity to Mate and faced the same problem. I found a solution, hope it helps.

central panel -> ibus preferences -> advanced

unmark keyboard layout & global input method settings.

[image]

Comment: Didn't work for me. Do you need to restart anything after making this change? (Using Debian buster/bullseye for the record)