# How can I run a non-interactive ibus-setup or fix this misconfiguration in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ibus

Based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774237/dead-keys-accents-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04) I learned that somehow Ubuntu 16.04, after upgrading from 15.10, made accents stop working in all my applications, and that by running `ibus-setup` and accepting the dialogs would make the accents work again.

However I must run that command everytime I turn on my computer.

How can I (one of these two)...

- Fix this so it works as it worked in 15.10, with no workaround?
- Execute this command silently on my .bashrc? By *silently* I want to remark that the command should not expect input from user, but turn on ibus immediately for the keys to work.

Comment: Do you use multilanguage desktop? Have you tried disabling ibus?

Comment: Could you check that you have `ibus` set in System settings > Language support >  input method. so the system will start dbus daemon at boot.

Comment: @Sneetsher YOU ARE THE ONE. Promote it to an answer please...

Answer (score 0):

`ibus-setup` does not change any setting but it will ask you to start ibus daemon if not already running.

So check:

- System settings → Language support → input method: should be `ibus`

With that is set correctly, the system starts dbus daemon at boot without any user interaction.